# How can I kill requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)

Tags: android, request

I am using this code -->requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE) in my dialog box but when I click button and return my main and my app closes itself and returns this error --> requestFeature() must be called before adding content. How can I handle it or How can I kill my request after calling.

Thanks...

Comment: I handle this problem but thanks everyone to your interest:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess you use the

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
```

after the method  setContentView(layout) make you app crash

try this :

```
private void setFullScreen(){
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}

private void cancelFullScreen(){
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

hope it help you !

Comment: instead of requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)? thanks I will try:D

Comment: I know this is correct and I use this code my app but I need to use this and when my app restarts I dont need requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)this code how can handle it. Namely I should kill this after calling the first time.

Comment: you can store the app status,and use if else block to implement it ,likely if(firststart) do it and otherwise do nothing,your can use the  Shared Preferences store the status http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref